# Cannot read property of undefined when using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I have a rather odd issue that I can't seem to solve. I have written a code and I want to use it when a certain element has this specific class name, so I have done this:

```
function slide() {
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box'); 
    if(box.style.maxHeight !== "100px") {
        box.style.maxHeight = "100px";
        box.style.opacity = "1";
    } else {
        box.style.maxHeight = "0";
        box.style.opacity = "0";
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<h1 onclick="slide();"> Text </h1>

<div class="box">
    <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.
    </p>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.box {
    max-height: 0;
  }
```

I think I am missing something here, but I don't know what. **The funny thing is: when I would use `getElementById`, it works! But I want to use classnames instead** and that is not working.

The error I am getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxHeight' of undefined

Comment: `var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0]; `

Comment: Oh dear me! Wow, that simple? Could you please write it down as an answer and explain to me what it does to be precise? It works, but I want to know why I need to do that?

Comment: byID returns 1, byClass returns many. choose one of the answers offered ;)

Comment: Thanks dandavis. I wanted to give it to you, but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get  *Elements*  By ClassName returns a HTML Collection. You need to assign it on each elem:

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box'); 
for(box of boxes){
 //work with elem
 if(box.style.maxHeight !== "100px") {
   box.style.maxHeight = "100px";      
   box.style.opacity = "1";
 } else { 
   box.style.maxHeight = "0";     
   box.style.opacity = "0";
}
}
```

Comment: Could you give it as an example, using my snippet? Don't get what you mean

Comment: Edited, now contains working code...

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much!

Comment: First time I see a `for...of` on a HTMLCollection. Is their [Symbol.iterator] standard? Unlike NodeList, the spec doesn't say they are iterable.

Comment: @Oriol dont know...

Answer (score 0):

```
   var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
```

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]

Answer (score -1):

the `getElementsByClassName` return an array. Its items have the `style` property, not the array itself.